# PHPstorm code paste indent

Tags: phpstorm, indentation, paste

I have following problem:

When I hit new line in PHPstorm (this line has indent) and paste some code, this code appear at the beginning of line. It's really annoying to indent every paste code.

Is there some way how to configure this?

Comment: `Settings | Editor | Smart Keys -> Reformat on paste`. You can also use `Code | Auto-Indent Lines` on selected text.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys -> Reformat on paste`

[image]

You can also use `Code | Auto-Indent Lines` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + I</kbd> using Windows keymap) on selected lines to re-indent them without applying the actual code formatting rules (lines breaks, force braces etc.)

**P.S.** `Edit | Paste | Paste as Plain Text` (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + V</kbd> here on Windows keymap) can be used to insert the text as is without any help from such smart helpers.

Answer (score 9):

This setting moved to a slightly different location in the menu structure in **Webstorm**.  Go to

```
Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Reformat on paste
```

and then select `None`.

`Smart Keys` is now a submenu on the `General` menu, which is different from another answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

Switching off `Reformat on paste` altogether (as suggested in some answers here) might not be what you want.

Instead, you can avoid the reformatting at any single paste action by not using `Paste` but `Paste Simple` (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-V).